# From the browser, how to make the web server refresh/invalidate a cached static-html-webpage?

Tags: html, web-applications

### PROBLEM:

Today, we modified a static html web page in a client's website - 
we added a couple of images and modified the font. And FTPed the file to client's web server. 
We realized we made a mistake with the font-size, corrected it, and FTPed the file again.

Even with a 100 refreshes, the website was displaying only the file (with wrong font) that we had FTPed the first time.

We FTPed the corrected file several times, but the file with the wrong font was the only file being  served by the web server.

### OUR GUESS:

We think that the web server cached the file that we had FTPed the first time, and is serving it back to us on subsequent requests even though the file had changed.

We tried the following techniques (but were unsuccessful):

1. We added a parameter to the querystring (?R=33343545)
2. We tried the technique suggested below - i.e. posting to the webpage in question, but got a "405 Method not allowed. The HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed."
   http://www.mnot.net/blog/2006/02/18/invalidation

Please advise if we were on the right path and if there is anything else that we can try in such situations ?

### EDIT:

We would like to find out if there is a way (similar to the 2 methods above) to do it just from the browser..and not touch the settings on the webserver.

Comment: Does this happen with all pages ? Probably it's a setting in the webserver that needs to be adjusted.

Comment: Since it is a static page, the web server is probably caching it.  You might have an earlier time stamp on the new uploaded page or something like that.  Also, you can have your client set up their web server such that it will not try to cache your static page.

Comment: @iDifferent - we modified only one page, so we don't know.. We will have to check the next time we modify more than one file.

Comment: @Bjoin Li - your suggestion about timestamp is interesting.. We are in a different timezone as the webserver..Can that cause any issues like this? The webserver is IIS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proxy cacheing - What about cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334393/proxy-cacheing-what-about-cookies)