# Same network users use same session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

There is a problem that I can not understand when working with Codeigniter Session Library. **Same network users use same session** (We work with a big company, and they said me this: When anybody logged in to system, then everybody logged in)! Is this possible? How, and what can I do for fix this bug?

I am using Codeigniter Core Session Library and it uses database.

Comment: Did you set `sess_use_database` to `true` within the config? If so, then this could be the cause. Your entire company will use a single external IP address and this will be used to match and return a session. However, I'm pretty sure (as @Natrium said) this still requires a cookie?

Comment: Now, I just checked log table and see that there are multiple users with different IPs. Tomorrow I will go to the company hq and check server details completely. Maybe this will help.

Comment: Yes, there is a proxy caching in Company. So please check out these links; https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching?hl=tr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334393/proxy-cacheing-what-about-cookies

Comment: Just to be sure, have you set `sess_match_ip` to `false` and `sess_match_useragent` to `true`? Your cookies should not be shared amongst other users, but as a test, it could be worth creating a cookie and checking it on another machine on the same network and see if it's then pulled down?

Answer (score 1):

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

> When a page is loaded, the session class will check to see if valid
>   session data exists in the user's session cookie. If sessions data
>   does not exist (or if it has expired) a new session will be created
>   and saved in the cookie. If a session does exist, its information will
>   be updated and the cookie will be updated. With each update, the
>   session_id will be regenerated.

I don't know where you read that same network users use the same session, but in the CodeIgniter-documentation, I find that the session is stored in a cookie, and network users will not have the problem you discribed.

Answer (score 1):

It is more possible to have app logic error that a session one.
Maybe you can reproduce it if you try on your local development server to use 2 ore more different user accounts (from different browsers).